# Custom dimension not populated by GTM

Tags: google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I have two sites set similarly, where I have a 'hit' level custom dimension in Universal Analytics. In GTM I have a tag which populates this custom dimension with a time stamp. 
In one of the sites, the custom dimension gets populated. In the other it doesn't. In the screenshot you can see the GTM debug pane for the fired tag in the site that's not working. It seems like GTM is sending the data over - but for some reason I can't see it in Google Analytics (and in the other site it is)
[image]

Comment: did you check if the indexes are right?

Comment: yes, they're correct

Comment: Are you able to share your sites?

Comment: do you mean to give you permission for the analytics and gtm?

Comment: there is a "Share" option in GTM, which shares a preview link to your website, with the debugger on.

Comment: Just want to see your sites, but @Barnett has a good suggestion, too, to share the preview mode.

Comment: Barnettt, sorry for the late answer - had to get permission from the site owner - and yes, I can share.

Comment: OK, please post the share link here, or PM someone to help you.

Comment: that's the share link: https://www.googletagmanager.com/set_cookie?uiv2&id=GTM-KP85Z4&gtm_auth=5KhHAPsLtvqiquEHCoo4mg&gtm_preview=QUICK_PREVIEW&gtm_debug=x
And this is the site: www.hacara.org.il

Comment: Strange, it all seems to be perfectly working. Did you tried to pass some of these dimensions as events (for example - the clientID as event label, to check it's received by analytics)